# Missing text for reaching the First Answers review queue

Tags: bug, review

I've reached the review limit for the First Answers queue in Super User. It renders a blue rectangle on https://superuser.com/review, but instead of having some explanatory text in it, it's empty:

[image: Screenshot of a list of review queues, with the First Answers queue having an empty blue box below it]